# Does RDP use up a lot of CPU on the remote machine?

Tags: performance, remote-desktop, docking-station

I have a laptop with an 8th gen i7 U processor that I use for programming when I'm outside.  At home I have a powerful desktop PC with 3 QHD monitors (2560x1440).

What I have been doing is RDPing into the laptop when I want to do work at home.  The quality is pretty good but once in a while, the rendering lags slightly.  Does it take up a lot of CPU which I could be using for compiling?

Remoting into a server I have no worries about, wondering if these mobile processors can handle it.

My other option is to buy a USB-C dock but those are about $250.

Comment: Have you tested it?  While at work, occasionally look in Task Manager with programs sorted by CPU usage.  Connect from home later, continue working normally, look at Task Manager again.  If you're already stuck home because of the quarantine, there are other programs that you can leave running saving logs or a graph while you're disconnected, then compare to while you're connected.  In my personal experience, total CPU usage is not significantly changed by hosting RDP as long as you're not running videos or other heavy-visual activity that must be compressed and transmitted.

Comment: I agree with the comment above that using RDP does not cause a CPU issue.  It has not for me.  An alternative to consider is Radmin Server on the laptop. It runs as a service. The viewer is free and run run on your desktop on demand. I have Radmin Server running on my Desktop and access it from wherever I happen to be.

Comment: the issue is usually from the network side rather than the CPU. Try reducing the quality to [15 or 16-bit color](https://serverfault.com/q/491460/343888). That'll reduce the required bandwidth to a half or 2/3 while still maintaining decent color representaion. You can even [force RDP to use 8-bit color](https://superuser.com/q/590110/241386)